# How can I export the type of an Action creators return value using Flow?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, flowtype, flow-typed

I'm currently exporting 2 action creators:

```
export const login = (payload: $PropertyType<Actions.Login, 'payload'>): Actions.Login => ({
  type: LOGIN,
  payload,
})

export const logout = (payload: $PropertyType<Actions.Logout, 'payload'>): Actions.Logout => ({
  type: LOGOUT,
  payload,
})
```

These are their respective `actions:

```
export type Login = {
  type: ActionType,
  payload: {
    username: string,
    password: string,
  },
}

export type Logout = {
  type: ActionType,
  payload: null,
}
```

In another file, I import the creators using the wildcard syntax

```
import * as Actions from ...
```

I'm then trying to extract from these actions the shape of their return type to use as the action type for my reducers.

What I'm trying to obtain is the following (I think, as I'm assuming this is what Flow is expecting to satisfy the reducers requirements – a `type` property):

```
type Action = { 
    login: { type: '', payload: '' }, 
    logout: { type: '', payload: '' } 
}
```

I've reached this function:

```
type Action = $ObjMap<typeof Actions, <V>(V) => $Call<V>>
```

Which returns the following:

```
Action: type Action = { 
    login: Login,
    logout: Logout
}
```

Which is indeed the actions returned from those creators. However, Flow within the reducer is not picking up on the `type` property within that action.

The reducer looks like this:

```
const reducer = (state: State = initialState, action: Action): State => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOGIN:
      return { ...state }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

With the error at `action.type` being:

```
[flow] property `type` is missing in object type [1]. (References: [1])
```

Any help into writing a better, generic function is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First, import the type of the module exports from the module containing the action creators:

```
import typeof * as ActionCreators from './actions'
```

This will be an object type, so the [`$ObjMap`](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-objmap) utility helper can be used to map each action creator to it's type of the return value. What requires attention here is:

- to ensure the action `A` returned from an action creator is exact
- to utilize [`$Values`](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-values) to get a union of all the exact action types

The following should result in a type that contains the union of all possible actions returned by creators which can easily be refined by the `{ type }` property in reducers:

```
type Action = $Values<$ObjMap<ActionCreators, <A>((...any[]) => A) => $Exact<A>>>
```

You can view this example on [Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0MYewdgzgLgBAhsKBLcBhATgUzlE6ICyIAJgK4A2mMAvDAN4BQMM5IA5kmAFwwAUpETOjBwAtph7R0nNgBoYABzgQIAdzzFJUaWDYBKGgD4+jZsygBPBRL4ByVhzC2e99p1t7ZTM0ous4mvQwAkIi4vJKKuroxDAAvt5xnt4OIKRQPLwG1Ma8pmaW1pmubGlQzjAlZR5eZopwfiABPGAU5Il6DAkMhVQAgogoYBjYuPg0ML0gAGbwg2hYOHiEJBSYPVb982ATACQAanDkpJgQADy7APIARgBWBHAKZwPIC6PL8s+GvLwAdP9wMAWADaAF1ssY+hCYLsAKIADwQUC+hkM3mYDGmpDA2xgWDIwCEvCRQx4LyGBnyaiQUGAAAs+CTwL9epT0TBiJhpnAKBl2QBIADcxO2LM2PEwogUlk6zAScSAA) to see it in action. Notice how for the `login` and `logout` action types, the default case of assigning the action type string to be empty `;(action.type: empty)` raises errors that `action.type === 'login'` and `action.type === 'logout'` have not been handled.